# after build openjdk1.9 in mac, cannot find gamma program

Tags: debugging, jvm

i work with jdk in osx, and build one openjdk1.9 in my mac successfully.
But there is one thing confuses me, i find no gamma program and launcher.script, which alway exist in openjdk1.7 and openjdk1.8. 
can anyone help ?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want this? gamma launcher was removed in [JDK-8008772](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8008772).

Comment: sorry to reply late. i want to use gamma program aimed at debuging jdk.

Comment: So, you don't actually want gamma launcher, but rather look for a way to debug JVM. You can do this with standard `java` launcher by adding `-XXaltjvm=<path>` argument that points to your debug JVM.